# Sequelize js get count of associated model

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

Say for example I have a `discussions` table and `replies` table.

How do I get the count of replies for each discussion record ?

```
Models.course_discussions.count({
    where: { 'course_id': 105 },
    include: [
        {model: Models.course_discussions_replies, as: 'replies'}
    ]
})
.then(function (discussions) {
    if (!discussions) {
        reply(Hapi.error.notFound());
    } else {
        console.log("91283901230912830812 " , discussions);
    }
});
```

The above code is converted into the following query -

```
SELECT COUNT(`course_discussions`.`id`) as `count` FROM `course_discussions` LEFT OUTER JOIN `course_discussions_replies` AS `replies` ON `course_discussions`.`id` = `replies`.`discussion_id` WHERE `course_discussions`.`course_id`=105;
```

The above code gets me count of discussions. But how do I get the count of the replies for each discussion ?

The following sql query works, but how do I write it in the sequelize way ?

```
SELECT COUNT(  `replies`.`discussion_id` ) AS  `count` 
FROM  `course_discussions` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `course_discussions_replies` AS  `replies` ON  `course_discussions`.`id` =  `replies`.`discussion_id` 
WHERE  `course_discussions`.`course_id` =105
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need the discussions and the replies count maybe `.replies.length` should work for you.

```
Models.course_discussions.findAll(
  where: { 'course_id': 105 },
  include: [
    {model: Models.course_discussions_replies, as: 'replies'}
  ]
})
.then(function (discussions) {
  // each discussion in discussions will have a
  // replies array

  discussions[0].repies.length // replies for current discussion
});
```

Comment: To prevent the database from doing a bunch of work and returning the entirety of the associated rows, you could also add `attributes: ['id']` to the query.

Comment: What if you need to add conditions on the count? For instance, find all the discussions with at least 2 replies?

Comment: `let twoRepliesDiscussions = discussions.filter(discussion => discussion.replies.length > 2);`

Comment: This is actually a poor response since it retrieves all of the rows to do the count in JS. Better to use built-in DB functions.